# ngForOf doesn't work in angular 9 nested in turbo table

Tags: angular, primeng-turbotable

I use Angular 9.1.3 and Primeng 9.1.2 and I can't access to some data.

I use the table of primeng (aka turbotable), and I have a ngForOf to access some data. Here some code of the html :

```
<p-table [value]="sensors" dataKey="serial_number">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" ngFor let-bearing [ngForOf]="bearings" let-i="index" let-first="first">
        <tr *ngIf='bearing !== null'>
            <th>{{bearing}}</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                {{'TCW.SHARED.SN' | translate}}
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-rowDatas-center">
                    <span translate="TCW.SHARED.BEARING_NAME" [translateParams]="{value: bearing.setpoint}"
                        class="text-ellipsis d-inline-block" style="max-width: calc(100% - 19px)"></span>
                    &nbsp;<span class="fa fa-info-circle position-relative top-minus-1px"
                        [pTooltip]="bearing | bearingConfig" [escape]="false" tooltipPosition="bottom"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="position-relative">
                    <p-progressBar [value]="bearing.progress" [showValue]="false"></p-progressBar>

                    <div class="remaining-time" *ngIf="!bearing.isEnded"
                        [ngClass]="{'reverse': bearing.progress <= 49}">

                        <span
                            class="fa fa-hourglass-half x0-8"></span>&nbsp;<span>{{bearing.remainingS | humanDuration}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

But when i serve my app I've got this error : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setpoint' of undefined`
I see with some console.log() than my bearings variable is undefenied when the constructor method of my .ts is call. But in the OnInit bearings works well.

I have the same code working in angular 5 with datatable of primeng.

Do you have an idea why didn't work here ?

Thanks.

Comment: you are checking for null, but not undefined. `*ngIf="!!bearing"` might help. your ngFor looks pretty old school, how about `*ngFor="let bearing of bearings; index as i; first"`?

Comment: It works really well, thank you!